# Android ProGuard +MultiDex causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, proguard, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

I have `MultiDex` enabled in my android project. It was working fine until I tried enabling proguard. I can successfully build the project but I get runtime exception on startup. It's unable to find the Application class and the `MainActivity`. I had the same problem before enabling `MultiDex`. Now I guess for some reason the `MultiDex` is not working properly with `ProGuard`. Here is what i get in the logcat -

```
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): install
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
02-17 19:01:09.750: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.750: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<mypackage.activities.MainActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<mypackage.activities.MainActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: D/AndroidRuntime(2079): Shutting down VM
02-17 19:01:09.751: D/AndroidRuntime(2079): --------- beginning of crash
```

and after that the rest of the stack trace is about ClassNotFoundException for the MainActivity:

```
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Process: com.mypackage, PID: 2079
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mypackage/activities/MainActivity;
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at cmypackage.application.ApplicationContextProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.activities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     ... 12 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.activities.MainActivity
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         ... 14 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MainActivity
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         ... 13 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**Edit-**
Here is my proguard rules file:

```
-libraryjars libs

# We only want obfuscation
-keepattributes InnerClasses,Signature

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-verbose

# Sdk
-keep public interface com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }
-keep public class com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }

# Appcompat and support
#-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
#-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
#-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
#-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

# Gson
-keep interface com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

# Retrofit
#-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
#-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
#-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
#-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
#-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
#-keep interface retrofit.** { *; }

# Retrofit
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# Jackson
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class mypackage.parsers.JacksonParser.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}

#Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#-dontwarn javax.management.**
#-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
#-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
#-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
#-dontwarn org.json.*
#-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

#-keep class javax.** {* ; }
#-keep class org.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Im getting similar issues

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) says:

> The default `proguard.cfg` file tries to cover general cases, but you
>   might encounter exceptions such as `ClassNotFoundException`, which
>   happens when ProGuard strips away an entire class that your
>   application calls.
>
> You can fix errors when ProGuard strips away your code by adding a
>   `-keep` line in the `proguard.cfg` file. For example:
>
> ```
> -keep public class <MyClass>
> ```
>
> There are many options and considerations when using the -keep option,
>   so it is highly recommended that you read the ProGuard Manual for more
>   information about customizing your configuration file. The Overview of
>   Keep options and Examples sections are particularly helpful. The
>   Troubleshooting section of the ProGuard Manual outlines other common
>   problems you might encounter when your code gets stripped away.

### Solution 1

You could try the following `proguard.cfg` I used to obfuscate the code while not optimising, and hence not remove classes/methods from your APK.

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-verbose
```

### Solution 2

You have asked some classes to be kept but not for `MainActivity`. So you have to add this line:

```
-keep class com.mypackage.activities.MainActivity { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try your suggested rules but i am actually trying to optimise the code. Since MultiDex is causing runtime exceptions on some the pre-lollipop devices. So, i am trying to use proguard to optimize code and may be reduce memory usage. bw i am adding all the rules to proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: and adding these rules didn't help. I am still getting the same exception

Comment: "and adding these rules didn't help. I am still getting the same exception", I think you have not commented the previous commands of the proguard and that's why it isn't helping.

Comment: what previous commands ? i have a lot of rules in proguard file. You can have a look at it.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question; i have already tried adding exceptions for MainActivity and even for the whole project but still the same issue. I guess it has to do with MultiDex as you can see in the stacktrace